# div, without trigger horizontal scroll

Tags: html, css, scroll, margin

I'm trying to create this design for a WP template:
http://minus.com/lbi1iH25EcKsu7

Right now I'm like this: http://www.uncensuredftw.es/plantilla-blueftw/boilerplate/index.html

I think you can get the general idea ;)

I know...*it's my fault*: The browser calculate the size of the window from left to right, so if I put a margin it will move the div with the 100% size to de right.

But the thing is: **I don't know how to make it work** :(.

I wanted to make the "black bars" with divs (I painted the ones than don't work in red and orange) and the trick worked...but only the left ones works like I want.

I'm getting out of ideas. I tried like everything I could think off, and nothing works.
**Maybe you can help me?** ;)

This is the html code:

```
<div class="barraUL"></div><div class="barraDL"></div>
<div class="presentacionbg"></div>
<div class="presentacion">
<div class="barraUR"></div><div class="barraDR"></div>
```

And this the css:

```
.barraUL {
   position: absolute;
   width: 50%;
   height: 27px;
   background-color: black;
   right: 50%;
   margin-right: 500px;
   margin-top: -20px;
}
.barraDL {
   position: absolute;
   width: 50%;     
   height: 27px;
   background-color: black;
   right: 50%;
   margin-right: 500px;
   margin-top: 309px;
}
/* This next two are the ones than "doesn't work" */
.barraUR {
   position: absolute;
   width: 50%;
   height: 27px;
   background-color: red;
   left: 50%;
   margin-left: 500px;
   margin-top: -4px;
}
.barraDR {
   position: absolute;
   width: 50%;     
   height: 27px;
   background-color: orange;
   left: 50%;
   margin-left: 500px;
   margin-top: 325px;
}
```

Comment: What's the problem exactly? The right bars aren't displaying gradients?

Comment: Can u make a fiddle with it so that we can work on it [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Kwon, the problem is the horizontal scroll...the "bars" are ok, but I want to be able of resize the window to 1024 or like that without trigger the horizontal scrollbar. As you can see in the link, the two right bars (the colored ones) trigger the scrollbar because of the margin :(

Comment: Singh, here: http://jsfiddle.net/arkdelkaos/tEu55/ ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right divs are expanding to 50% the window width. For a liquid layout where the bars extend to the length of the window and then cut off, you'd usually make an underlaying div (in this case the bars and the black patterned background) and then expand it to 100% of the window. You can't make an additive layout using relative lengths like percent (left div + fixed middle image + right div) with just CSS (especially not with absolute positioning). If you insist on using this, you'll have to `overflow: hidden;` the `html {}` or `body {}` tag after centering your content and that's just bad practice. I recommend just having two long divs go all the way across the screen under your sprite image.

Comment: I think I understand what you tell me, but I don't know for sure if it's right...because the sprite has a transparency in the middle, and if I make a upper bar from left to right, 100% size, and another one down, they're going to show under the transparency...or not? Maybe I misunderstand what you tell me.

Comment: ...but, between you and me, I'm starting to think about change the design to something easier ;) But it's feel unfulfilling, you know what I mean :( That part of the design was the part I liked more.

Comment: Oh..........¡hidding the body overflow works! O___o
BUT: **Why it's a bad practice?**

Comment: Ok, I see the problem: The "overflow" center div will show the scrollbar "displaced".
I think there's no way for this design to work with only css (and I don't want to make js fixes)

Comment: Well...I think the "new" effect it's ok ;) Thank you very much for the help.